# How to create a UEFI read only variable?

Tags: uefi

On an EFI system that boots GRUB2, I want to create a read-only EFI variable.  Is this possbile?

Comment: These are two separate questions, please trim down to ask only one thing at once (and post the other one separately).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Uefi Specification 2.7](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Spec_2_7.pdf) there is a straight forward way of creating a read-only UEFI variable post ExitBootServices() by not providing EFI_VARIABLE_NON_VOLATILE attribute.

See Chapter '8.2 Variable Services' SetVariable() description:

> Once ExitBootServices() is performed, only variables that have
>   EFI_VARIABLE_RUNTIME_ACCESS and EFI_VARIABLE_NON_VOLATILE set can be
>   set with SetVariable(). Variables that have runtime access but that are not nonvolatile are read-only data variables once ExitBootServices() is performed.

See also Chapter '8.2 Variable Services' GetVariable() Related Definitions:

```
//*******************************************************
// Variable Attributes
//*******************************************************
#define EFI_VARIABLE_NON_VOLATILE 0x00000001
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [UEFI Specification 2.5](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI%202_5.pdf) there is no straight forward way of creating read-only UEFI variable.

Expecting result can be achieved by using variables with *Attributes*: EFI_VARIABLE_AUTHENTICATED_WRITE_ACCESS and EFI_VARIABLE_TIME_BASED_AUTHENTICATED_WRITE_ACCESS.

According to chapter 7.2 (SetVariable description part) of UEFI Spec 2.5:

> (...)
>   An attempt to delete a variable created with the EFI_VARIABLE_AUTHENTICATED_WRITE_ACCESS or 
>   EFI_VARIABLE_TIME_BASED_AUTHENTICATED_WRITE_ACCESS attribute for which the 
>   prescribed AuthInfo validation fails or when called using DataSize of zero will fail with an 
>   EFI_SECURITY_VIOLATION status.

According to chapter 7.2.1 (Using the EFI_VARIABLE_AUTHENTICATION_2 descriptor), after long procedure describing variable update process:

> The driver shall update the value of the variable only if all of these checks pass. If any of the checks
>   fails, firmware must return EFI_SECURITY_VIOLATION.

Concluding, it is impossible to delete or modify variable, that was created using *_WRITE_ACCESS attributes, without authentication. `GetVariable` will return correct value indicating in attributes that returned variable requires authentication before update or delete. For more information please read UEFI Spec 2.5 chapter 7.2.1 and 7.2.2.

Comment: The Authenticated attributes have nothing to do with read-only variables. Authenticated Variables are writable, you just have to sign your payload with the right key. Read-only properties can be achieved by not providing EFI_VARIABLE_NON_VOLATILE attribute as answered by @Pshemy108 below.

Comment: Agree, my answer was provided 3 years ago an maybe not up to recent spec. I have to revisit it as soon as I will find some time. Feel free to edit this answer.